# Auto hide element by jquery - code not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element in aspx page with class= "._aHide"  it carrying a message, And it is shown repeatedly.

```
<div id="Message1" class="._aHide" runat="server" visible="true"><p>My Message</p></div>
```

- aspx server side elements not created when page load if it's visible property = true.

I need to hide this div after 7 seconds of show it, unless mouse over.

I created this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hide = false;
    $("._aHide").hover(function () {
    clearTimeout(hide);
    });

    $("._aHide").mouseout(function () {
    hide = setTimeout(function () { $("._aHide").fadeOut("slow") }, 7000);
    hide;
    });

    $("._aHide").ready(function () {
    hide = setTimeout(function () { $("._aHide").fadeOut("slow") }, 7000);
    hide;
    });
});
```

But somthings wrong here

1- this code work for one time only, And I show this message many times.

2- All message boxes hides in one time, because I can't use $(this) in settimeout and I don't know why.

Thank you for your help, and I really appreciate it

Comment: hide; doesn't help, it is a syntax error. Remove it

Comment: what is with the `hide;` line?

Answer (score 4):

Remove the point in the HTML code:

```
<div id="Message1" class="_aHide" runat="server" visible="true"><p>My Message</p></div>
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: using non alphanumeric characters in `class` or `id` is asking for headaches ( excluding hyphen or underscore)

Comment: Sorry, the point is write mistake and it is not in code, I just add it here when write the post. its not the problem. and many thanks for your interest and answer

Answer (score 1):

tbraun89 is right, remove the "." in your html code.

Then, you can simplify your code like this :

JQuery [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) have 2 functions using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hide = false;
    $("._aHide").hover(
    function () {
        //Cancel fadeout
        clearTimeout(hide);
    },
    function(){
         //re-set up fadeout
        clearTimeout(hide);            
        hide = setTimeout(function () { $("._aHide").fadeOut("slow") }, 7000);
    });

    //Set up fadeout
    hide = setTimeout(function () { $("._aHide").fadeOut("slow") }, 7000);
});
```

Comment: thanks for  help, but still has the same problems, work only one time, and all hides in the same time.